# How can I overlap text/emoji in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Here's what I am trying to achieve (it's just for fun. I hope it's ok to post here):

[image: Overlapping emojis]

The "text" I want to overlap is actually emojis.  If you look at the screenshot above, I want to combine the two emojis on the right to get the effect on the left.  I applied the text effect "Reflection" on the crying emoji.  I want the reflection to come out of the grinning emoji instead.  I call this combination "Hiding the Pain".

Here are the requirements:

- It has to be done within Outlook.  While it's probably possible by making it in an html file with css and then send the file as email body, it's way too technical.  I am hoping there is a way anyone can learn to do it.
- Can't use pictures.

In the screenshot, I put one of the emoji in a textbox which allows me to overlap, but once it's sent out, it does not look like that, it looks cursed.

I tried messing with character spacing and line spacing, couldn't get it to work.  Need to get creative on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some more attempts, I found a way.  The key is to use Equations.  Here are the steps:

1. Insert an equation under the Insert tab.  It defaults to align center, so change to align left.  Up the text size and turn off italic.
2. Under Equation tab, select Matrix, then "2x1 Empty Matrix"

[image]

3. In the top square, enter the text/emoji that is going be overlapped; in the bottom, enter the text/emoji that is going to be overlaying.

[image]

4. Then we are going to lift the bottom part upwards.  Highlight the bottom part, right click, select Font.  In the Font window, under Advanced tab, select "Raised" in the Position dropdown, and enter the number of pt to move by.  You may need to try a few times to get this number.
   [image]

Then we are done!

[image]

Note that the reflection effect only seems to work in desktop Outlook.  I tried opening the email in web and mobile, the reflection is lost in both, but the emojis are still stacked together.

Worth mentioning that, one way to stack emoji is to use the "Condensed" option within the Spacing dropdown in the Font window I showed above.  It makes emojis stick close together horizontally.  This doesn't work with reflections.

[image]

Using textbox seems to be an easy solution, but I couldn't get it to work.  Still, appreciate John's answer.  It looks like this in my outbox:

[image]

You could say it looks even better (in some way), but what the recipient sees is only the black outline of the emoji for some reason.  In this case, I copied what I see in my outbox and sent it to people.

Didn't waste too much time at work at all.

Comment: Can you clarify *"I tried opening the email in web and mobile, the reflection is lost in both, but the emojis are still stacked together"*

Comment: @BlindSpots If the recipient opens the email in web Outlook or mobile client, they see the grinning emoji on top of the crying, but don't see the reflection of the crying emoji.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses either (a) text (which is too simple for this) or (b) basic Word for regular Outlook word processing.

To overlap text, you need to build a text box, add the character, and again, and overlap the text boxes.

I have tested this on a New Email, set to HTML, and Styles and Text Boxes are readily available.

That is how this will work.

> Need to get creative on this.

Done above.

Comment: Thanks John.  Did you try sending out the email?  In my attempts, any emojis in textbox get messed up once the email is sent.

Comment: If you overlap the text as I showed how to do within HTML using text boxes, then it should not get messed up The recipient will see the overlapping in the email they get. Be sure to set for HTML

Comment: If what you are doing / using does not work, then there is nothing more you can do. What I have posted allows you to overlap text, as you requested. That is all that is available.

Comment: Thanks, it probably works for overlaying text, but I couldn't get it to work with emojis.  I found a way that gets me exactly what I wanted.  See my answer.